# Retrieve indices of matching points in another array

Tags: python, numpy, indices

Total blank on how to do this.

I have an array "points" and an array "a" containing some of those points:

```
points = numpy.array([[1,2],[4,0],[3,0],[2,4]])
a = numpy.array([[1,2], [3,0]])
```

How can I get the indices in "points" of points in a ([0,2]), preferably without loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an O(n²) operation and is not meant to have a direct method without a loop.

The following solution works for any size of 2D variables of `points` and `a`.

```
import numpy as np
points = np.array([[1,2],[4,0],[3,0],[2,4]])
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,0]])


np.array([np.argwhere((points==a[i]).all(axis=1))[0][0] for i in xrange(a.shape[0])])
# returns array([0, 2])
```

However, this does not work for values of `a` missing from `points`.

Answer (score 0):

For many points, put `a` in a [scipy.spatial.cKDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html), then do a query to find the nearest `a` to each `point`.
This takes O(N ln N) for randomly distributed points, see [Kd tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree);
the loops are in cython, so fast.